# Garminn GSc10 reset problem

Tags: garmin

How do you reset the GSC10 sensor on Garmin edge 510?  I want to be able to re-pair it to my device.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the menu that shows the paired sensors delete the sensor you want to remove. 510 will ask for a confirmation. Then re-pair the sensor. It may help to remove the battery from the sensor and putting it back after a minute.

Answer (score 2):

Using the sensor menu on your edge 510, delete the sensor.

Make sure you have a fresh CR-2032 battery in the GSC 10 Speed & Cadence sensor.

There is a button on the bottom right corner of the GSC 10.  It acts as an indicator light as well as the reset button.  Hold it down for 5 seconds.  It should flash red and green.

Press the SEARCH button in the sensors meny of the EDGE 510.

Spin the wheel.  It will flash each time the wheel rotates for a few seconds, then it will go dark.

The EDGE 510 should pop up a message saying "Speed & Cadence sensor FOUND"

Comment: Thank you, I think be refinding the sensor it got the wheel size proper.